# Saxon PE and EE return different results from format-date

Tags: xpath, saxon

The following xpath expression appears to produce different results in different editions of Saxon:

```
format-date(xs:date('-0800-01-01'), '[Y]')
```

Specifically, Saxon-**E**E 9.9.1.5 produces "799", whereas Saxon-**P**E 9.9.1.5 produces "800". I'm invoking this code via an XSLT in oXygen v22.0.

Anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a different configuration setting for handling of negative years. There was a change from XSD 1.0 to XSD 1.1 - XSD 1.1 aligned with ISO 8601 by using the astronomers' convention (which has a year 0) rather than the historians' convention (which does not). Saxon has a configuration switch to select XSD 1.0 or XSD 1.1 rules, and this affects the handling of years before the Christian era.